# Translate Ruby snippet to Java

Tags: java, ruby

How can I do the equivalent of the Ruby snippet below using Java?

```
require 'net/http'
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("http://somewhere.com/isalive")).body
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://somewhere.com/isalive");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

and then, if you want, you can transform the `InputStream` to `String` using `IOUtils.toString(inputStream)` from apache commons-lang, or something like [this](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/266.html).

Update: the above classes should be imported first, with a statement ontop of the class definition:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
.. and so on
```

Comment: The place I need to use the Java doesn't look like it's got the IOUtils library. How can I read the stream into a string without it?

Comment: Turns out I could use IOUtils I just needed to prefix it with org.apache.commons.io.

Comment: @sipwiz: or import it, just like the other classes. Note that the code above will use the platform default encoding to convert the input stream to a String, which can corrupt the data. To avoid that, you should use the HttpURLConnection class and look at the content-type response header. Or use the Apache HTTP client library which can do this automatically.